# HTML pattern in character#2354 format

Tags: html, regex

How can I make a pattern which requires the user to type in the format

string#number
The string can contain any  character other than #

eg robert#2345
bob34#7805
linda_2#3444
!3eve3!#5545

This is what I have right now

```
pattern="[]+#[0-9]$"
```

thanks for the help in advanced

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: At the top "I want to make a pattern which requires the user to type in the format"

Comment: Try `pattern="[^#]+#\d+"`. If `string` cannot have whitespace, try `pattern="[^\s#]+#\d+$"`. Note you do not need `^` and `$` at both ends of the pattern since the HTML5 pattern is anchored by default.

Comment: You just need `pattern="[^#]+#\d+"`

Answer (score 0):

> string#number
>
> The string can contain any character other than #

Based on your description of the problem, you can use the following pattern:

```
^[^#]+#\d+$
```

However, this allows **any** string before the `#`. You might want to be a bit more restrictive - e.g. no whitespace:

```
^[^#\s]+#\d+$
```

Or perhaps only some "whitelisted" characters, e.g.:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_!:.,-]+#\d+$
```